# Question about finding consistent seat number using sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I found a code to find the consistent seat number for a movie theater. But I can't understand what is ':head_cnt', especially its grammar. Could anyone explain :head_cnt ? (I searched on google but got nothing helpful.) Many Thanks!

```
SELECT 
    s1.seat AS start_seat,
    '~',
    s2.seat AS end_seat
FROM 
    Seats s1, Seats s2 
WHERE 
    s2.seat = s1.seat + (:head_cnt -1 )
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 
                         *
                     FROM 
                         Seats s3
                     WHERE 
                         s3.seat BETWEEN s1.seat AND s2.seat
                         AND s3.status <> 'available')
```

Here is the original table:

```
CREATE TABLE Seats
( seat     INTEGER      NOT NULL,
  status   VARCHAR(32)  NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(seat));
```

status has two values : 'available' or 'reserved'

Comment: tag your sql engine

Comment: postgresql. I just added it on.

Comment: in your code, there should be a variable called `:head_cnt`.

Comment: I almost want to give up this [:head_cnt]. can't find it anywhere...

Comment: Hard to answer unless you specify what a "consistent seat number" is.

Comment: "*But I can't understand what is ':head_cnt'*" - that's most certainly a parameter ("placeholder", "bind variable") provided during query execution from within some programming language

Answer (score 1):

any string starts with **:** is basically a binding variable. You can pass it during run time. To explain you mode clearly, below snipping has select **:head_cnt** , which asks user to enter the vale. If the value is provided as Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow will be displayed. Like wise this binding variables can be passed in the where clause as well. You can also define it as a run time argument.

[image]